# Codeigniter PHP обращение к базе

Tags: php, codeigniter

подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать такой вопрос. Есть таблица отзывы, на странице product. На странице продукт товар например имеет $product->id == 1. Хочу ограничить отзывы на странице продукт и выводить только otzivi->id == $product->id ; sql запрос выглядит так `SELECT * FROM` otzivi`WHERE`id `= " . $product->id ."`, а как можно запихнуть в модель значения product->id ?  Хочу на выходе получить  $this->db->where($id,'. $product->id.');

```
function fetch_details($limit, $start)
 {
  $output = '';
  $this->db->select("*");
  $this->db->from("otzivi");
  $this->db->order_by("id", "DESC");
  $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  $output .= '
  <table class="table table-bordered">
   <tr>
    <th>Country ID</th>
    <th>Country Name</th>
   </tr>
  ';
  foreach($query->result() as $row)
  {
   $output .= '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
    <td>'.$row->name.'</td>
   </tr>
   ';
  }
  $output .= '</table>';
  return $output;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Закинуть через POST в контроллер product->id, далее через функцию это значения передать в модель и подставить в sql запрос.